# MySQL WHERE IN and another variable equal

Tags: mysql

I'm running the following query expecting to receive back the first 3 rows, however all I am getting is the first row.

**Query Ran**

```
SELECT * FROM inventories WHERE id IN ('1,2,3') AND state = 1
```

**Database**

[image: Data]

**Result**

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    uid: 1,
    name: 'An Epic Item',
    suggested_price: 29212,
    image: 'http://hanatemplate.com/images/emoji-ok-7.png',
    state: 1 } ]
```

Why is it not returning the first three rows instead of just the first one?

Comment: `IN (1,2,3)` they are numbers not a comma delimited string

Comment: '1,2,3' is a string mysql will attempt an implicit conversion to an integer (assuming that's what id is) and stops at the first comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't return any, since you've got the list enclosed in quotes (but see below). Try

```
SELECT * FROM inventories WHERE id IN (1,2,3) AND state = 1
```

As per the comments, SQL converts your string to an integer, 1, which is why  you get the first record.

Comment: That seems to be it indeed, but I put in the array of ids like so, `[].toString()` - how could I still do it that way?

Edit: nevermind it's because I was escaping the string.

Comment: How can I still make sure the ids are escaped (as they are user provided)?

Comment: You don't escape numbers.

Comment: which programming language are you using? @Borda i believe you mean prepared statements with escape?

Comment: I think he means the user provides the list of id numbers (as a string). So the solution is to parse the string to extract that list of numbers (or verify that it is a list of numbers and just include it in the query string without the quotes).

Comment: "SQL converts your string to an integer" You mean MySQL, iám pretty sure that SQL standard definition is to give a error when the database executes `SELECT (1) IN('1, 2, 3')`.. MySQL is more or less more lose with SQL standards.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: yes, that's what I meant, but I haven't tested it. I was just going on P.Salmon's comment on the OP question.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson so my best bet would just be to write a function to check if the provided array actually exists of numbers?

Comment: @Borda. I guess. I don't know your full process flow, but it seems like a straightforward solution for most cases.

Comment: "yes, that's what I meant, but I haven't tested it" Yes P.Salmon is right auto conversion is happing..  `SELECT (1) IN('1, 2, 3')` results in `1` when executed in MySQL.  and `SELECT (2) IN('1, 2, 3')` in `0` and `SELECT (2) IN('2, 1, 3')` results in `1`

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson could I just filter out any string that is not a number like so;
`array.filter((arr) => !isNaN(parseInt(arr)));` - that way I would not have to do any additional checks.

Comment: parseInt('1,2,3') will give 1, though, not NaN.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson that's fine, just want to make sure it's not vulnerable to any attacks

Comment: Ah sure, then it's good. (You could also attempt to convert the resulting int back to a string and compare it against the original string. If it's the same, then the user will get what is expected. If not, you can issue a warning instead of running the query so that the user is not misled).